# Transition maps between coordinate charts on the Grassmann manifold

Tags: smooth-manifolds, manifolds, grassmannians, affine-grassmannian

Let $\mathbf{Gr}_{n,k}$ be the manifold of $k$-dimensional subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^n$, and let $\mathbf{col}$ be the map that takes a matrix in $\mathbb{R}^{n\times k}$ to its columnspace. The map
\begin{align*}
\varphi:\mathbb{R}^{(n-k)\times k}&\to\mathbf{Gr}_{n,k} \\
A&\mapsto\mathbf{col}\left(\frac{I_k}{A}\right),
\end{align*}
where $I_k$ is the identity, is an injection into $\mathbf{Gr}_{n,k}$. Further, if we have integers $i_1,\ldots,i_k$ satisfying $1\leq i_1<\ldots<i_k\leq n$, then the permutation matrix $P_{i_1,\ldots,i_k}$ that takes row $j\in\{1,\ldots,k\}$ to row $i_j$ and row $j\notin\{1,\ldots,k\}$ to row $j^\prime$, where $j^\prime$ is the $j$th smallest element of $\{1,\ldots,n\}\setminus\{i_1,\ldots,i_k\}$, allows us to make a similar injection from $\mathbb{R}^{(n-k)\times k}$ into $\mathbf{Gr}_{n,k}$:
$$\varphi_{i_1,\ldots,i_k}:A\mapsto\mathbf{col}\left[P_{i_1,\ldots,i_k}\left(\frac{I_k}{A}\right)\right]$$
The set of all such $\varphi_{i_1,\ldots,i_k}$ comprises an atlas on $\mathbf{Gr}_{n,k}$.

My question is: say we have $L\in\mathbf{im}\varphi_{1,\ldots,k}\cap\mathbf{im}\varphi_{2,\ldots,k+1}$, and say $A=\varphi_{1,\ldots,k}^{-1}(L)$. How can we compute $\varphi_{2,\ldots,k+1}$ in terms of $A$?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. You have a formula for arbitrary $\varphi$ in your question.